# If I put mkfs.ext3 file from another Linux system on my android ,will it work?

Tags: linux, terminal, huawei-u8160, armv6

I want to know if I take the `mkfs.ext3` file, or any other mkfs file, from another Linux system like Ubuntu, and put it with my `mkfs.vfat` and `mkfs.ext2` located at `/system/xbin`, Would it work?

And how can I call them from terminal emulator?

<sup>If relevant, I have a Huawei u8160 running Cyanogenmod 7.2.</sup>

---

**EDIT:**

I realized that it cannot be taken from Ubuntu or any non-ARMv6 built system ,so my question now is: Where can I find binaries that are built for ARMv6 phone? (at least mkfs ones(except mkfs.vfat and mkfs.ext2,I already have them) ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Native binaries (as the `mkfs.*` tools are) need to be compiled for the platform they should run on. So if you take the `mkfs.ext3` from your Ubuntu workstation, which probably is either x86 or x86-64, it will not work on your Android device, which most likely uses ARM architecure.

Comment: is there is any other way to make it work ,take it from another android phone maybe?

Comment: and yes,it uses ARM v6.

Comment: if you take it from a compatible platform (i.e. also ARM v6), it *could* work. When compiled statically, it *should* work. Otherwise (compiled dynamically) it depends of the libraries used: if those are available on the target system, it should be no problem. (btw: this explanation was not specific to the binary in question, but rather generic to all native binaries).

Comment: could you find anywhere that I can find ARM v6 binaries (at least mkfs ones)?

Comment: In case you find a compatible one: You call it as usual by its name. When called without parameters, it should yield its syntax requirements (as it did last time for your `mkfs.vfat`). In case you get some "not found" instead, invoke it with the full path, e.g. `/system/xbin/mkfs.ext3`.

Comment: no I mean where can I find the file because I don't know anyone with ARM v6 phone

Comment: come meet me in chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25/android

Answer (score -1):

Since I think there aren't reliable sources for these binaries you could prefer to compile it (statically) using [busybox](http://www.busybox.net/) with a [cross compiler](http://www.mentor.com/embedded-software/sourcery-tools/sourcery-codebench/overview).

You are using cyanogenmod so should be also easy to compile it using the cyanogenmod source code (search on their site since I can't post more link :)), busybox is in the `external/` directory.

Comment: For to compile, using CM, requires to download around 9GB of source code, it would be nightmare just to download one small tiny part of what makes up CM, or basically, use google-fu to navigate around the net as am sure others would have attempted it :)

Comment: I understand, but at first I talked about downloading directly busybox so downvoting seems a little bit excessive to me :). Also is not a good practice to install on your phone software found around the web

Comment: Hummm... I did not downvote you...

Comment: ok, sorry for the misunderstanding